# Creating new encrypted instance from existing Amazon Aurora instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have basic knowledge in AWS .Trying to setup another encrypted instance from existing Aurora instance .
As I know we cannot convert instance directly to encrypted .Here is the steps what i followed.
But problem is how to make encrypted version live with the same state of non-encrypted instance. Is it like we need to set replication from non-encrypted to encrypted instance?

Comment: Could you clarify the question, not able to understand what the query is exactly. What is the error you are seeing in the above set of commands? Is your goal to create an encrypted cluster from a non encrypted snapshot?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Hi Karthik,  Here I have 1 aurora MySQL instance which is unencrypted. i want to convert it to encrypted without stopping the instance.

Comment: Is live migration needed or is it okay to migrate with some downtime? As in create a snapshot, restore and then flip traffic? I guess the downtime is - you would need to stop writes after you create your snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the exact same steps as migrating from an RDS Mysql instance to an Aurora Mysql cluster, but a minor difference that in your case, the source is an unencrypted aurora cluster and target is an encrypted mysql cluster.

Detailed steps:

1. Create a snapshot from your unencrypted cluster
2. Restore a new cluster from that snapshot, but enable storage encryption. You end up getting an encrypted cluster.
3. Setup `binlog` replication on your old cluster
4. Update your new cluster to use the binlog replication
5. Fade out your writes from old cluster to new cluster
6. Check replication status on the new cluster to know if you've caught up
7. When you're ready, turn off the old cluster.

Docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Replication.html

Comment: Thanks for the update ,I tried above steps but issues while  restoration of snapshot . cluster that is restored not showing any instances . Here is the AWSCLI command . `aws rds restore-db-cluster-from-snapshot --db-cluster-identifier encrypted-one-cluster-snapshot1  --snapshot-identifier one-cluster-snapshot  --kms-key-id 04121125-114f-22a3-adc1-02cf32be3123 `.

Comment: Restoring a snapshot just creates a cluster, which is nothing but a new storage volume. You need to explicitly add instances to it using the create-db-instance API.

Comment: @saikumarEce Do you need anything else as part of this question?